# $N$-dimensional volume (of revolution)

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, area

Consider the system of coordinates $\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\}$ and an n-dimensional shape such that, in $\{x_{1},x_{n}\}$ (and $x_{2}=x_{3}=...=x_{n-1}=0$) it is inside the lines $x_{n}=ax_{1}+b$ and $x_{n}=0$.

If the shape is so symmetric that the same holds for $\{x_{1},x_{2}\},\{x_{1},x_{3}\},...\{x_{1},x_{n}\}$ (I'm basically rotating over $x_{1}$ this line), and $x_{1} \in [0,r]$, how do I get the volume of the resulting shape?

Comment: That isn't enough to define the shape. It says nothing about whether $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ is inside or out when more than two of the $x_i$ are non-zero.

Comment: assume that inside

Comment: Then your volume is quite obviously $\infty$ (assuming $n > 2$). You've included almost every point in $\Bbb R^n$ inside it. The only points *not* in it lie on a finite number of 2-dimensional planes.